Are X and Y independent( No probability density functions)?
Let Ω be a square with corners at points (1, 0), (0, 1), (−1, 0), and (0, −1), and let X and Y be defined by the x- and y-coordinates, respectively, for a randomly chosen point in Ω. Let $U = X + Y$ and $V = X − Y$.
(a) Are X and Y independent?
(b) Are U and V independent?
I know that X and Y are independent if they joint probability density function = product of marginal PDF. But we don't have those and to assume that X and Y are uniformly distributed between (-1,1) is not correct because our square are rotated in the plane.
This makes it hard for solving task b since there we would (theoretically) use the transformation theorem and the Jacobian to get joint PDF.
Any suggestions?

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then this would imply, for example, $$\Pr[Y > 1/2 \mid X > 1/2] = \Pr[Y > 1/2].$$
Is this true?  Can you sketch a diagram to show whether it is true or false?
As for $U$ and $V$, what are the possible outcomes for these?  Sketch another diagram, and ask yourself what this suggests.  Try to guess the joint density of $U$ and $V$, then use this guess to try to prove it algebraically.

Thank you for quick answer. So you are using counter example?
If X and Y are independent then P(X|Y) = P(X) for all X,Y in Ω.
I guess that P(Y > 1/2 | X > 1/2) = 0 since when X is greater than 1/2 Y value is locked between 0.5 and -0.5 hence probability is zero. But  probability for Y > 0.5 is certanly isnt zero (it should be the area of the square where y > 0.5 i guess?). is this the approach in your reasoaning?
But i dont rly get the part with diagrams

@MrPink Correct.  $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent.  Did you draw a diagram for the joint density of $X$ and $Y$?  Based on this diagram, what are the lines of constant $U$?  For example, what does the line $U = 1$ look like?  Where is the line $U = 1/2$?  Similarly, what does the line $V = 1$ look like?  Does this give you an idea of how you would plot the joint density of $U$ and $V$?

Can you explain what you mean with diagram for join density. I dont get that part

@MrPink You are told that $\Omega$ is a square with corners at $(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1)$.  So draw this square on a Cartesian coordinate plane, with the usual $x$ and $y$ axes.  The point $(X,Y)$ is chosen uniformly at random inside this square.  So $\Omega$ (the square and its interior) is the joint support of $(X,Y)$.  The density is uniform on this square; if you think of the density function as being represented by a height $z = f(x,y)$ on this square, the height must be constant, and it must be such that the volume under the function must be $1$.

So what must be the height that makes the volume under the joint density equal to $1$?  Remember that Volume = Base x height.

I appreciate your time for answering. I did from the start drew the square in the plane ofcourse. there i could see for instance that P(Y > 1/2 | X > 1/2) = 0. But i dont get how i could get a function for from here. And what do you mean with volume? do you maybe mean area? I mean usually we would make a transformation from X,Y to U,V. then calculate the jacobian etc. but we cant assume that X,Y are uniformly distributed since the square is rotated. I mean if X,Y - U(-1,1) that would mean that we are dealing with a normal square in (-1,-1) ,(1,1),(1,-1) and ( -1,1) but thats not the case here

can anyone please explain?
